# Substituting place holder image for jsonp image object with a value of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

Using angular I'm making an ajax jsonp request to retrieve channels from the twitch.tv api. A few of the channels do not have logo images, so I would like to put a placeholder image for channels with null logo object. I created an object '$scope.imgs which has two properties current: data.logo which are the logo images from twitch.tv api, and replaceData which is the image url to the replacement image i'd like to use as an image placeholder. I created an if statement to test weather data.logo is null and if it is replace the src attribute string with the replacement image string, but i'm using ng-src, so I wanted to know how i can target ng-src and if I am taking the right approach to replacing the channnels with a null image object values?

there is more code but this is the portion I'm having difficulty with..

```
$http.jsonp(url + streamers[i] + callback).success(function(data) {

                        $scope.imgs = {
                            current: data.logo,
                            replacement: "http://www.zwani.com/graphics/hello_funny/images/56467.jpg"
                        }

                        if (data.logo === null) {
                            $scope.imgs.current = $scope.imgs.replacement;
                            var replaceData = $scope.imgs.current;
                            console.log($scope.imgs.current);
                            document.getElementsByTagName('img').src = replaceData;
                        }

                        self.info.push(data);

                    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-complicating it . All you need is to update the property with your url string.

Angular will take care of displaying it for you

```
$http.jsonp(url + streamers[i] + callback).success(function(data) {
   var placeholder ="http://www.zwani.com/graphics/hello_funny/images/56467.jpg";
   if(!data.logo){
       data.logo = placeholder ;
   }
   self.info.push(data);    
});
```

Comment: WOW! I really went around the world .. thanks @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

You could also just let the data.logo be null and then in your html do something like this...

```
<img ng-src="{{$scope.imgs.logo || 'http://www.zwani.com/graphics/hello_funny/images/56467.jpg'}}">
```